# Optimal algorithm for finding the girth of a sparse graph?

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, graphs

I wonder how to find the [girth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girth_%28graph_theory%29) of a sparse undirected graph. By sparse I mean $|E|=O(|V|)$. By optimum I mean the lowest time complexity.

I thought about some modification on [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) for undirected graphs, but I didn't find good results. Actually I thought that if I could find a 2-connected components in $O(|V|)$, then I can find the girth, by some sort of induction which can be achieved from the first part. I may be on the wrong track, though. Any algorithm asymptotically better than $\Theta(|V|^2)$ (i.e. $o(|V|^2)$) is welcome.

Comment: This is probably still an open problem and perhaps better suited for cstheory.

Comment: Actually if it's an open problem, it's not suited there either. But the question itself if it had an answer would seem to fit better on cstheory.

Comment: Also, why doesn't BFS work ?

Comment: @Suresh: BFS is $O(|V|)$ for sparse graphs, but you might have to run it $\Omega(|V|)$ times. Did you have something else in mind?

Comment: No that's correct.

Comment: But it would appropriate to ask on cstheory whether this is an open problem.

Comment: @Suresh, I can't think better than $\Omega(n^2)$ for BFS. Also if this is suited for CStheory I'll ask it there tomorrow.

Comment: Note: this question has been transferred to cstheory. Voting to close.

Comment: @Suresh: Rather than closing, we should just add an answer here with a link to the answer there, saying it was answered in cstheory. Besides, what would we close it as? Off-topic? (I have added a CW answer).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Optimal algorithm for finding the girth of a sparse graph](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10983/optimal-algorithm-for-finding-the-girth-of-a-sparse-graph) from cstheory.SE which has an accepted answer.

Comment: I think answer in CSTheory is not complete, I'm waiting for more references so I didn't mark it as answer yet. But here you can decide to close this, but I'm not going to delete it because I think it's good to have history of this problem in CS. P.S: I know Shiva is excellent in related fields, but still I think it's better to leave it open, may be someone else has better references.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri: You might not always find a reference. It is possible that no one considered this problem before, or made an explicit note of it in some open problem list. You can always leave your question unmarked though. btw, I am against closing it here. This is a perfectly valid question for this site, and closing this might give the wrong impression to future questioners.

Comment: take a look at the cstheory question now.

Comment: See also [Lecture on a Cycle in a Graph](http://corner.mimuw.edu.pl/?p=285).